# Printing unpacked list

Tags: python

I can't understand why the second time the t_matix is looped over, nothing is printed.

- In Python 2.x the second print is done correctly.
- In Python 3.x (at least 3.6.3) that second print is not done.

What is happening with that t_matrix variable between the 2 loops?

```
matrix=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)]
for row in matrix:
    print(row)
print("\n")
t_matrix = zip(*matrix)
for row in t_matrix:        # first print, printed ok
    print(row)
print('-' * 80)
for row in t_matrix:        # Second print, nothing shown
    print(row)
```

Comment: `zip` returns a list in python 2, and an iterator in python 3.

Comment: Ok... But in Python 3  the first one printed and not the second one. The syntax is the same, so what happened with the t_matix variable?

Comment: It's all explained in the questions I linked.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see the links the first time...